# How do it safely with optional bindings

Tags: ios, swift

After all long time later i build  `makeResult`  to display in the `label` but problem it is to much  code  here .  how  can I reduce the code? .

```
   @IBAction func value_Array(_ sender: AnyObject) {

            var hobbies = [String]()

           // print(jsondata["hobbies"])

            hobbies =  jsondata["hobbies"] as! [String]
            var makeResult : String?
            for (index, value) in hobbies.enumerated(){
                print(value)
                makeResult =  (makeResult != nil ? "\(makeResult!) \n" : "") + " your \(index+ 1) is \(value)"

            }
            outputResult.text = makeResult != nil ? makeResult : " "
        }
```

Note : *Since I have to unwrap `hobbies` anyway  how do it safely with optional bindings .*

Comment: Great, what is your question?

Comment: @JAL thanks .How  can I reduce the code?

Comment: You should make your code safer rather than shorter.

Comment: @vadian please guide me how can I do that ? I am trying ...

Comment: Since you have to unwrap `hobbies` anyway do it safely with optional bindings.

Comment: PS: And `(key, value)` is actually `(index, value)`

Comment: How to reduce code? Really? At least explain what are you doing there and what do you need from there

Comment: *Hint:* Use `map(...)` and `joined(...)`

Comment: @EridB i want to make my code safer and  shorter . i try to perform each comment vadian, MartinR , they are  guiding  a lot of thing for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want safely and succinctly.

```
@IBAction func value_Array(_ sender: AnyObject) {

  guard let hobbies = jsondata["hobbies"] as? [String] else {
    outputResult.text = ""
    return
  }

  outputResult.text = hobbies.enumerated().map { index, element in
    return " your \(index + 1) is \(element)"
  }.joined(separator: " \n")
}
```

Comment: perfect thanks ... i am waiting for this type of solution

Answer (score 0):

This may not be smaller but it is much safer. This will not crash if there is no hobbies data.

```
@IBAction func value_Array(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  guard
    let hobbies = jsondata["hobbies"] as? [String],
    hobbies.count > 0
  else {
    outputResult.text = " "
    return
  }

  var index = 0
  outputResult.text = hobbies.reduce("") {
    index += 1
    return $0 + ($0.isEmpty ? "" : " \n") + " your \(index) is \($1)"
  }
}
```

An alternative to using the internal `index` variable is to zip together the indices and hobbies into a tuple first. But this makes the string creation line more complex; your choice.

```
@IBAction func value_Array(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  guard
    let hobbies = jsondata["hobbies"] as? [String],
    hobbies.count > 0
  else {
    outputResult.text = " "
    return
  }

  outputResult.text = zip([1...hobbies.count], hobbies).reduce("") {
    return $0 + ($0.isEmpty ? "" : " \n") + " your \($1.0) is \($1.1)"
  }
}
```